# Elastic json deserializer with java

Tags: java, json

Is there any simillar json parser to javascript `JSON.parse()`?

I receive messages with different schemas and want to parse them all without the knowledge about the schema.
For example sometimes it can be:

```
{
  type: "aaa",
  xxx: "xxx",
  yyy: {
     xx: "xx"
  }
}
```

and sometimes:

```
{
  type: "bbb",
  xxx: [{ppp: {aa: "aa"}}],
  zzz: "xx"
}
```

The only common thing is a `type` attribue and I want to handle it according to it like in javascript:

```
const d = JSON.parse(msg.toString());

if (d.type === "aaa") {
  handleAaa(d);
}

if (d.type === "bbb") {
  handleBbb(d);
}
...
```

Comment: You could parse into a JSONNode or a LinkedHashMap, but wouldn't advice you to do this. Are you okay to conditionally parse into different schema?

Comment: all solutions are welcome. The most efficient (lighweight for CPU) will win. I need it to parse websocket messages, making near real time streaming data analysis.